# Binding interceptor to NestJS microservice method

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I just created a simple interceptor to override every error thrown by my application, just like the one on Nest's documentation:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ErrorsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next
      .handle()
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => throwError(() => new ApplicationException())),
      );
  }
}
```

And altough exceptions caused by http requests indeed are caught in that interceptor, I just can't make it work with RPC requests (like KafjaJS and events).
Just like the documentation, I've binded it on my `app.module`:

```js
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: ErrorsInterceptor,
    }
```

I know I'm probably missing something out, can someone clarify where and why what I'm doing is not working and how to make it work?

**@Edit:** I forgot to mention that I made it work @UseInterceptors() above my controller's method, but I'd like to make it work without it.

**@Edit 2:** I have a hybrid appplication, this is what my main looks like (as asked by Jay):

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {
    logger: WinstonModule.createLogger(winstonTransports),
  });

  app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(kafkaConfig);

  const logger = app.get<winston.Logger>(WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER);
  app.useLogger(logger);
  app.enableCors(corsConfig);

  await app.startAllMicroservices();
  await app.listen(env.PORT);
}
```

Comment: Is this a hybrid application (RPC and HTTP) or just a microservice server? How does your `main.ts` look?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed! I just added an example of it on my question!

Comment: My bad, it is indeed a hybrid application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with hybrid applications you need to add `{ inheritAppConfig: true }` to the `connectMicroservice()` method as a second parameter [as described in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application#sharing-configuration). This means your `main.ts` should be

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {
    logger: WinstonModule.createLogger(winstonTransports),
  });

  app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(kafkaConfig, { inheritAppConfig: true });

  const logger = app.get<winston.Logger>(WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER);
  app.useLogger(logger);
  app.enableCors(corsConfig);

  await app.startAllMicroservices();
  await app.listen(env.PORT);
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but I'm pretty sure when I tried using this property kafka stopped receiving messages!

Comment: Marked your answer as correct because it did work even tough I have a new problem with microservices lib as I mentioned... I'll try to figure out a solution, but thanks for the help!

Comment: @Lucas what is the new problem with the microservices lib? Were you able to figure it out? I suspect I might hatve the same issue.